# second button can only be clicked if first button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this script for a clock where when you click on start the current time gets displayed. the same happens when stop is clicked. What I want to happen now is that when I click on the first button that the second button gets activated as in you can only click the second button when the first one is clicked.

My HTML

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/new-style.css">
  <title>Digital Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
  <button class="panel2" onclick="CurrentTime()">Start rit</button>
  <p>Start van de Rit: <span id="Start Rit" /></p>
  <button class="panel1" onclick="ZaWarduu()">Stop rit</button>
  <p>Einde van de Rit: <span id="Einde Rit"/></p>
  <p>Clock : <span id="Clock" /></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </center>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Javascript code

```
    //Met deze functie word de tijd op dit moment laten zien in de html code met het id:clock
    var time;
    function ItsShowTime(){
            var date = new Date();
            var h = date.getHours();
            var m = date.getMinutes();
            var s = date.getSeconds();

            h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
            m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
            s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
            time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

            document.getElementById("Clock").textContent = time;
            setTimeout(ItsShowTime, 1000);
    }

    //Met deze functie zorg je ervoor dat als je klikt op start rit de tijd op dit moment er komt te staan.
    function CurrentTime(){
      //var value kijkt hoeveel er word geklikt op de knop start rit. Je kan dat zijn door de pagina te inspecteren en naar console te gaan als je daar eenmaal bent klik op start rit dan zie je hoe de var value omhoog gaat bij een laat hij de tijd zjin bij twee komt de alert te staan.
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('Start Rit').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementById('Start Rit').value = value;
      console.log(value);
      // deze if statement zorgt ervoor dat als er nog een keer geklikt word op start dat er een alert oppupt.
      if (value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("Start Rit").innerText = time;

      }
      if(value != 1){
        alert("Rit kan niet opnieuw gestart worden.");
      }
    }
    function ZaWarduu(){
      var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Einde Rit').value, 10);
      value2 = isNaN(value2) ? 0 : value2;
      value2++;
      document.getElementById('Einde Rit').value = value2;
      console.log(value2);
      // deze if statement zorgt ervoor dat als er nog een keer geklikt word op start dat er een alert oppupt.
      if (value2 == 1) {
        document.getElementById("Einde Rit").innerText = time;

      }
      if(value2 != 1){
        alert("Rit kan niet opnieuw gestopt worden.");
      }
    }

    function KeepTime(){
      if (Location.reload(DigitalClock.html)){

      }
    }
    ItsShowTime();
    KeepTime();
```

I looked at a couple of similar questions on stack overflow and tried to look at some search result in google unfortunatly I couldn't find anything.

Comment: add html `disabled` property to second button and remove the property in click function of first button, could be as simple as `document.getElementById('panel1').disabled = false;`  this works for most browser

Comment: @johnSmith Hey thanks I didn't think the solution was so simple thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share a state between these two buttons via localStorage for exemple, or via a store like Redux if you want to add complexity :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let sw = 1;
    function show(a) {
        if (sw == 1 && a == 1) {
            document.getElementById("leaf1").style.display = "block";
            sw = 2;
        }

        else if (sw == 2 && a == 2) {
            document.getElementById("leaf2").style.display = "block";
            sw = 3;
        }
        else if (sw == 3 && a == 3) {
            document.getElementById("middle").style.display = "block";
            sw = 4;
        }
        else if (sw == 4 && a == 4) {
            document.getElementById("red1").style.display = "block";
            sw = 5;
        }
        else if (sw == 5 && a == 5) {
            document.getElementById("red2").style.display = "block";
            sw = 6;
        }
        else if (sw == 6 && a == 6) {
            document.getElementById("red3").style.display = "block";
            sw = 7;
        }
        else if (sw == 7 && a == 7) {
            document.getElementById("red4").style.display = "block";
            sw = 8;
        }
        else if (sw == 8 && a == 8) {
            document.getElementById("red5").style.display = "block";
            sw = 0;
        }
        else {
            alert("choose your wrong images.");
            document.getElementById("leaf1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("leaf2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("middle").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("red1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("red2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("red3").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("red4").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("red5").style.display = "none";
            sw = 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.